# Set switch track drawable and different text colors in OnText and OffText in code

Tags: android, xml, switch-statement

I created switch in code, not in xml.

```
Switch sw = new Switch(getActivity());
sw.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
sw.setTextOn(getString(R.string.ok));
sw.setTextOff(getString(R.string.remove));
sw.setSwitchMinWidth((int) (4.8 * pixels));
sw.setSwitchTypeface(font);
sw.setThumbResource(R.drawable.thumb);
```

Method setThumbResource is working well, but the method setTrackResource leads to the disappearence of switch.

My xml files for thumb and for track. They are almost the same.

**thumb.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

        <solid android:color="#a79d90" />

    </shape>
```

**track.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

        <solid android:color="#bfb5a7" />

    </shape>
```

Also, what I want to do is to set different colors for TextOn (green) and TextOff (red). I found only one method - setTextColor that leads to changing both colors.

Comment: Did you find something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For @DjimOnDev. I'm using this

```
            Switch sw = new Switch(getActivity());
            sw.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            sw.setTextOn(getString(R.string.ok));
            sw.setTextOff(getString(R.string.remove));

            if (sw.isChecked()) {
                sw.setSwitchTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.SwitchTextAppearance1);
            }
            else {
                sw.setSwitchTextAppearance(getActivity(), R.style.SwitchTextAppearance2);
            }

                sw.setSwitchMinWidth((int) (3.6 * pixels));
                sw.setThumbResource(R.drawable.thumb);
                sw.setTrackResource(R.drawable.track);
                sw.setSwitchTypeface(font);
```

**thumb.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >


        <solid android:color="#bfb5a7" />

    </shape>
```

**track.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/thumb_off" /> 
<item                               android:drawable="@drawable/thumb_default" />
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="SwitchTextAppearance1">
    <item name="android:textColor">#5db701</item>
</style>

<style name="SwitchTextAppearance2">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ea3d3d</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have posted answer on this link this worked for me.

[Switch Track Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138949/switch-track-color/36742528#36742528)

code from there:

```
if (isChecked) {
                    mSwtPrivacyView.getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.switch_track_checked_true_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                } else {
                    mSwtPrivacyView.getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.switch_track_checked_false_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                }
```