# Switch Track Color

Tags: android, colors, widget, android-switch

I want to use a Switch and change its Track Color. So in my opinion nothing spectacular.

My Switch layout:

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/Switch1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:track="@color/gray"
    android:textOn="@string/on"
    android:textOff="@string/off"     
    android:text="@string/musiconoff" />
```

and my color "grey":

```
<color name="gray">#666666</color>
```

My Problem is that the Switch is shown as a 1-pixel Switch. It's just a small line. If I delete the "color"-line, the Switch is correct (without grey of course).

Where is my fault?

Comment: use my answer on android:track="@android:color/darker_gray"i think there is problem in your @color/gray

Comment: and don't forget to vote me up

Comment: Can you accept answer of @Sector11 as it is only answer worked in every situation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nothing worked for me except this

```
if (isChecked) {
                    mSwtPrivacyView.getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.switch_track_checked_true_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                } else {
                    mSwtPrivacyView.getTrackDrawable().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.switch_track_checked_false_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
                }
```

Comment: This is very helpful for me.. Thanks @sector11

Answer (score 17):

Following code solves the problem:

**In you Activity/Fragment (XML):**

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/sMuteNotifications"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:checked="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
    android:thumb="@drawable/bg_thumb"       //  Create this drawable
    android:track="@drawable/bg_switch_states"/>       //  and this one too
```

**bg_thumb :***(Use this or any image you want)*

> Create this in your `drawables` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>

    <size android:width="28dp" android:height="28dp"/>

</shape>
```

**bg_switch_states:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_on_switch"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_off_switch"/>

</selector>
```

**bg_on_switch :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="18dip" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryLight"/>  // <---What ever color you want to use here
</shape>
```

**bg_off_switch :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="18dip" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>  // <---What ever color you want to use here
</shape>
```

There you go...

Hope this will help someone

Comment: thanks dude this is working perfectly ,we can customize track color and thumb also

Comment: Huge thanks, you saved my day! A well-explained example with the ability to customise colours and styles

Comment: instead of using android:track="@drawable/bg_switch_states", use app:track="@drawable/bg_switch_states"

Answer (score 9):

Here is a very simple solution, that worked for me. Just setup the xml attributes thumbTint and trackTint with color selectors. Track is the background component, thumb is the round component.

```
<com.google.android.material.switchmaterial.SwitchMaterial
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:thumbTint="@color/switch_thumb"
        app:trackTint="@color/switch_track" />
```

or even better add these items to your app theme to apply to all switches:

```
<item name="thumbTint">@color/switch_thumb</item>
<item name="trackTint">@color/switch_track</item>
```

switch_thumb.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:color="@color/[your desired color]" android:state_checked="true" />
     <item android:color="@color/[your desired color]" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

switch_track.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:color="@color/[your desired color]" android:state_checked="true" />
     <item android:color="@color/[your desired color]" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Simple and clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to build a drawable with your grey color, like and place it in the res/drawable folder:

track.xml:

```
<shape 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">

     <size android:width="48dp" android:height="22dp" />
     <solid
         android:color="#666666" />
     <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#666666"
        android:dashWidth="2dp"
        android:dashGap="1dp" />
</shape>
```

Add whatever size you want to have your stroke(if needed) and add this drawable as the track property.

Does this help?

Comment: I just updated my answer. I tried it and it works. It should work for you as well. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to change the track color of switch

```
 android:track="@null"
 android:background="@drawable/img_setings_toggle_on"
```

Answer (score -4):

```
android:track="@android:color/darker_gray"
```

Try this in your code

Comment: your color name and accessing color is not same

Comment: This makes the track a rectangle :(